# Why can I access FTP server only with the smartphone?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ftp

I have a very strange behaviour with some devices that run Windows CE with FTP.
The devices run under an open WLAN and have no firewall active on Windows CE. 
The access point of the WLAN have no firewall active both on the devices and on the stationary access points.
The windows CE computer is connected via ethernet directly to the device's access point.
There is a windows 2012 r2 server directly connected to the WLAN accesspoint.

the problem is the following:
if I try to access the FTP (with anonymous login) with an iOS or Android device using an FTP app, I can browse/download/edit the files inside the FTP.
If I try to access with ANY computer, I get a 10054 error and cannot estabilish a connection. 
I tryed all kind of software (FileZilla, TotalCommander, WindowsExplorer, WebBrousers, etc..) with all kind of settings (active, passive, TLS, no TLS) but no success.

[network sketch to understand better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCZb4.png)

EDIT 1:

[Total Commander output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPSyq.png)

if I try to connect in active, it get stuck after USER anonymous line and goes timeout

EDIT 2:

[iOS FTP configuration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X85Tf.jpg)

[iOS FTP configuration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CXLM.jpg)

here is the configuration of the connection in my iOS device. some settings are in italian but it should be pretty straightforward.

EDIT 3:

DHCP is disabled.

UPDATE 1:

I tried to change the username to FTP or GUEST or anything else, then it prompts me to enter a password but no matter what I enter it fails the loging.
So I think it is ok to enter as anonymous user since the FTP is configured to have **only the anonymous login**.

UPDATE 2:

Still no solution. I will try replacing the Siemens routers with Cisco routers because I guess that the problem is somewhere in the routers, since in other places with the same Windows CE PCs I can access the FTP.

Comment: Have you tried different modes (passive/active)?

Comment: It might help if you provide the debug output from FileZilla so that one can see where exactly it fails and maybe then find out why.

Comment: Which AP do mobile devices connect to?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes tried both. with passive I get a 10054 error, with active it just times out.

Comment: @gronostaj to the same Siemens AP that the windows CE devices connects to.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich posted in the EDIT

Comment: I suspect 1. You need active and 2. Windows CE is probably running a very old version of the protocol that mobiles still support (go figure...). but desktop OSes don't.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia but iOS devices connects with passive mode. see last update

Comment: Because the login fails, this isn’t related to active or passive mode. Try different users.

Comment: @DanielB even if the access is set to anonymous login? with the smartphone I login with user: anonymous pass: a@a.com

Comment: @Nedo Do the computers you tried with also connect to those APs or the front one?

Comment: @gronostaj the computers connects to the WLAN AP (like the mobile devices); that is the same that the AP of the devices with windows CE connect to. There is only one AP that generates the network (SSID: LOCAL-LAN and no password)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to isolate the devices inside a NAT under the Access Point. When I try to access the FTP port the traffic is now forwarded to the FTP of the device, and it works.